# JavaScript/jquery running button press events, when typing in text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a web app and I'm having issues with being able to type in text boxes without activating JavaScript events tied to key presses. I tried my best to figure out a way to disable all of these events while focused to the text box but to no avail. Is there any way to "focus" on text boxes to stop other events from running? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chesus, can you share a code sample? that'd help us quite understand the problem to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. On `focus` removed all events listeners and on `onblur` add all events listeners.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
  
  //Attach all the events
  input.addEventListener('focus', removeAllEventListner);
  input.addEventListener('keypress', myFunction);
  input.addEventListener('blur', addEvents);
  
  //On focus remove all the events
  function removeAllEventListner() {
    input.removeEventListener('keypress', myFunction);
    console.log('Event removed');
  }

 //Onblur add all event 
  function addEvents() {
    input.addEventListener( 'onkeypress', myFunction);
    console.log('Event attached');
  }

  function myFunction() {
    console.log('Keypress event');
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"  value="" >
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, but this solution worked for me! Thanks